# Filter rallygrid by tag selection

Tags: javascript, rally

I have a rallygrid object and a rallytagpicker object created. What I would like to do is filter the rallygrid to only include items which include **any** of the selected tags. I have tried a couple of different ways of accomplishing this but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code for the tagpicker:

```
this.tagPicker = this.add({
    xtype: 'rallytagpicker',
    autoExpand: true,
    listeners: {
        select: this._onTagSelect,
        scope: this
    }
});
```

So, the first problem I'm having is that *select* doesn't actually seem to fire when I select an tag from the drop down, and secondly, once it does fire how can I refresh the filter on the grid to include items with this new tag?

As it is right now I'm filtering using filter objects like the following:

```
{ property: 'Tags.Name', operator: 'contains', value: 'My Tag' }
```

It would be nice if I could store all the tags to filter by in an array and pass the whole array at once rather than having an individual filter object for each tag. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the change event instead?

To build the filters you'll want to just or them together for each tag:

```
Rally.data.QueryFilter.or([
    {
        property: 'Tags.Name',
        operator: '='
        value: 'My Tag'
    },
    {
        property: 'Tags.Name',
        operator: '='
        value: 'My Tag2'
    },
]);
```

Then to refresh the grid you can use its refresh method, passing the new filters:

```
grid.refresh({
    filters: [
        //filters here
    ]
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working because Rally.data.QueryFilter.or takes a single QueryFilter object to combine with another, not an array of them. Is there a way to combine several QueryFilter objects without making a call for each one? Actually, what would be idea is to just change an option in the storeConfig so that the filters default is to OR the filters together instead of AND.

Comment: The code above should work.  Rally.data.QueryFilter has static and/or methods to join an array of query filters together into one filter.  It looks like those are missing from the docs somehow.  I'll fix that soon.

Comment: It's telling me Rally.data.QueryFilter.or is not a function when attempting to use your code above. Any ideas?

Comment: You're right- I'll submit a defect to get this implemented.  We had this in the 1.x SDK and apparently it never got converted over.  Sorry for the goose chase.  In the meantime you'll have to just manually loop over your array of filters and join them together using the or instance method.